# Существует ли MariaDB модуль для PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, debian, mariadb

Или надо [php7.0-mysql](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/php7.0-mysql) использовать? Ничего не отвалится?

Comment: MariaDB совместим с MySQL, но не наоборот же. Т.е. ни о какой MariaDB модуль php7.0-mysql не знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MariaDB` и `MySQL` [ничем не различаются](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/upgrading-from-mysql-to-mariadb/) с точки зрения сетевого протокола взаимодействия и даже с точки зрения `API` и `ABI` клиентских библиотек.

> All your old clients and connectors (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, etc.) will work unchanged (no need to recompile). This works because MariaDB and MySQL use the same client protocol and the client libraries are binary compatible. You can also use your old MySQL connector packages with MariaDB if you want.

Поэтому отдельный модуль не нужен и используется всё тот же драйвер `mysqli` или `pdo_mysql`. Если с течением времени протоколы разработчикам придётся изменить - тогда появится отдельная библиотека, а пока - совместимы полностью.